# Regression of a complex model in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

This is just a simplified version of what I have to do.
I have to perform a linear mixed effects regression for the following model:

```
y~a1+F1+F2+(1|Effect1)+(1|Effect2)
```

The problem I have is coding the fixed effects.

```
F1=a2*(M-M1)+a4*(10-M)      if M >=M1
  =a3*(M-M2)+a4*(10-M1)     if M < M1

F2=a5*ln(R+a6)+a7*lnV       if V<100
  =a5*1.5+a7                if V>=100
```

M,R,V,y,M1 & M2 are given and so are the Effects1 & Effects2. Also it is a large data set.
I have to find the regression coefficients a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7. Is there a way to do this in R?Like specifying the coefficients as variables or any other approach.

Edit: I have removed the F3 term and modified the F2 term, because it was causing a lot of confusion and I am mainly concerned about the first 2 terms

Comment: I think it would be called a "nonlinear mixed model". I would recommend the `nlme` (non-linear mixed effects) package. For your `M` and `V` threshholds, I would use indicator variables to multiply the model terms to turn them "on" or "off".

Comment: The last expression looks like some sort of constraint, but it's unclear exactly what you want to happen outside the bound, ... and what R and M have to do with it. And V is not listed in the data variables.

Comment: I have to first perform a linear mixed model. According to the papers I have read the `lmer` function under the `lme4` package is recommended

Comment: The last expression has to be solved iteratively. R,M and V are data.(M1 and M2 are also known). But forgetting about the last term, just a way to program the first 2 terms will be helpful as well

Comment: @Gregor what did you mean by "For your M and V threshholds, I would use indicator variables to multiply the model terms to turn them "on" or "off"." Could you explain it please because that is my major concern

Comment: Presumably you have a fixed value `M1`. For your `F1` condition create an "indicator" variable in your data called, say, `M_gt_M1` which is 1 when M is greater than M1 and 0 otherwise. Then your `F1` condition is written as `F1 = M_gt_M1 * (a2*(M-M1)+a4*(10-M)) + (1 - M_gt_M1) * (a3*(M-M2)+a4*(10-M1))`. Essentially you create the "if" statement by multiplying by 1 or 0 depending if the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor. But how will I get a2, a3, a4 because according to my limited knowledge about regression we only get one coefficient per term. eg. F1 will have one coefficient and F2 will have one (Using indicator variables we get 2 coefficients, one for each case of F1)

Comment: Also any idea how to approach the second term, F2

Comment: Second term goes exactly the same way, you have a column in your data called `V_gt_100` which is 1 when `V > 100` and otherwise 0. Multiply your two `F2` conditions by `V_gt_100` and `1 - V_gt_100` as appropriate.

Comment: As to your regression comment, what you say is true of *linear* regression. That's why, way up at the top, I said your model is *nonlinear*. If you use the `nlme` package you can specify all the `a`'s in your model formula and estimate them all. (Someone else mentioned the `lme4` package. I generally prefer `lme4` to `nlme` for mixed models, but I don't think it does *non*linear mixed models. So for this model, use `nlme`.)

Comment: Okay, thank you for letting me know about that. I didn't know that non linear models help you specify coefficients. It is my first time doing regression and using R.
Also I found that the `lme4` package has a nonlinear function `nlmer`. I think it should be able to do what `nlme` does.

Comment: @Gregor Do you know how to incorporate two separate random effects in nlme? I can incorporate one:
`model<-nlme(y~f1+f2+ee,fixed=a1+a2+....~1, random=ee~1|Event,start=c(...))`

How to incorporate 2 such effects? i.e. something like this
y~f1+f2+ee+se, fixed=....,random=(ee~1|Event,se~1|Site), start+....)

Comment: In a list, as described in the help... see the `random` argument description of `?nlme`